# MVC 3 does not render editor template for object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC 3 application which should allow the user to display and edit values of different types. The view responsible for doing this does not neccessarily know about the type of the value (it is declared as object), but I want it to render the correct editor template. Right now I have this:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(n => attribute.ValueTyped) %>
```

attribute.ValueTyped is of type object. When ValueTyped is of type bool, MVC renders a check box (which is what it is supposed to do). However, as soon as ValueTyped is of a different type (so far I've tried int, double, string), MVC does not render anything at all.

How do I make MVC render the generic templates for int, double, string or whatever type my ValueTyped contains? Please note: I do not want to generate the text boxes myself, but I'd rather let MVC decide which editor template to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to pass the name of the editor template explicitly by passing it as the second argument. Based on your dynamic situation this could look like the following:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => attr.ValueTyped, attr.ValueTyped.GetType().Name) %>
```

Of course, your question is quite old - maybe you could update it with the answer you found?

Comment: I did not really find a solution. However, by now the property I wanted to use this for has been removed from the underlying data model, so the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

When setting up an MVC 3 application, the foreign keys that should allow drop down lists to select an item do not get rendered as drop downs, but as static inputs.  This can be resolved by creating a custom display and view for that field.
We will need to start by creating a custom partial view that will live in “~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/UserGuid.cshtml”, and “~/Views/Shared/EditTemplates/UserGuid.cshtml”.  The code for one is located below:

```
@model Guid

@{ 
    incMvcSite.Models.MvcSiteDB db = new incMvcSite.Models.MvcSiteDB();
    incMvcSite.Models.SecUser usr = db.SecUsers.Single(u => u.Guid == Model);
}
@usr.Display
```

This is a display for template that will look up the item in the referenced table and display it.  We also need an edit for template as follows:

```
@model Guid
@{ 
    incMvcSite.Models.MvcSiteDB db = new incMvcSite.Models.MvcSiteDB();
    SelectList items = new SelectList(db.SecUsers.OrderBy(i => i.Display).ToList(), "Guid", "Display", Model);
}
@Html.DropDownList("", items)
```

The edit for template is implemented as a drop down list.  Originally, we has used static HTML code, but the problem will appear of implementing a “prefix”.  Static HTML code does get handled by HTML helpers, so it’s recommended that you use the HTML.DropDownList().
To force the MVC framework to use the new Display and Edit for templates, we need to annote our model item an add the following line:
[UIHint("UserGuid")]

This will cause MVC to use the Display and Edit templates named “UserGuid”, which are just partial views.

Comment: While your answer explains how to render dropdown lists quite well, it does not address the issue of how I can make MVC automatically decide which template to use based on the type of the object I pass in.